# Merging multiple Objects, removing excess inner geometry for 3d printing 2.82

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode, bmesh

I tried searching but could only find old non-2.8+ related info

I am trying to merge 30 disks to a supporting geometry, and the intersecting geometry will not let me 3d print properly.
Boolean search removed the carve solver in 2.8

I have tried doing individual Boolean merge but get glitches

[image]

Can anyone suggest a ways or add-ons to make this seamless for 3d printing? preferably without doing an operation 30+ times

Thank you in advanced. Cheers

Comment: Try to post a blend with this part, but there is not a straight one click operation, from what i noticed, but we can check glitches if they can be fixed in some easy way ...

Comment: so turns out theres an Add-on called 3D Print toolbox!

Comment: Lucky you if it solved your issue, this addon mostly inspects a mesh, so I don't think the Clean Up > Make Manifold will solve your issue. If so, can you please provide full answer so others can benefit from your search? Thank you